# find inside json and remove object

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
{"fgdsgd":"11111","dsadsadsa":["ip","userAaaagent"],"fdsfsd":{"sadsdsaasd":false,"dates":null},"pxg":{"aaa":[{"active":1,"bbbb":"12"},{"active":1,"bbb":"123"}]}}
```

how can I search in this JSON the key xzxzxz? if=12 than remove the object it's in..
so I will get

```
{"fgdsgd":"11111","dsadsadsa":["aaa","ccc"],"fdsfsd":{"sadsdsaasd":false,"dates":null},"pxgxzxz":{"sdsds":[{"active":1,"xzxzx":"123"}]}}
```

in case it's the only one in the array I need to remove the entire pxg object

```
{"fgdsgd":"11111","dsadsadsa":["ccc","cccc"],"fdsfsd":{"sadsdsaasd":false,"dates":null}}
```

I need to do this in typescript

here is a my code in TS. But I get an error

```
const data = {
  "fgdsgd": "11111",
  "dsadsadsa": ["ip", "userAgent"],
  "fdsfsd": {
    "sadsdsaasd": false,
    "dates": null
  },
  "vvvvv": {
    "trackivvvvngIds": [
      {
        "active": 1,
        "cccc": "12"
      },
      {
        "active": 1,
        "ccc": "123"
      }
    ]
  }
};
        interface Tracxzxzkingxz {
        active: number;
        zxzxz: string;
    }

    interface vvvv{
        trackinvvvgIds: ccccc[];
    }

    interface pixels {
        fgdsgd: string;
        dsadsadsa: string[];
        fdsfsd: {
            sadsdsaasd: boolean;
            dates: null;
        };
        zxzxzx?: PxgOxzxbject;
    }
const xzxz= "12";

// Find the index of the object with the given pixzxzxzelId
    const index: any = pixels.pxg.trackinxzxzgIds.findIndex((obj: xzxzxz) => obj.xzxz=== xzxzxz);


if (index !== -1) {
  // Remove the object at the found index
  data.pxg.zxxz.splice(index, 1);

  // Remove the pxg object if the trackinxzxzgIds array is empty
  if (data.pxg.trackxzxzingIds.length === 0) {
    delete data.pxg;
  }
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: It's need to be written with typescript

Comment: you can just rename the file to .ts and then it's typescript. if you want more typing enable `strict` mode, `noImplicitAny` and `strictNullChecks` in typescript then fix the mistakes that are reported when compiling it.

Comment: I get a lot of errors as I dont declare the types. I tried many things but doesn't help

Comment: Please add the errors you receive, otherwise the question is incomplete.

Comment: I flagged this question because the author said in an already deleted answer, that he has solved the problem and updated the question (!) so that the problem doesn't arise. If this is correct, the question is useless for the community. So, the question should be reset to the original question and an appropriate answer should be added, or the whole question should be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just missing the Types:

```
type MonitoringModeType = {
    isMonitoring: boolean,
    dates: Date[] | null
}

type PxgType = {
    trackingIds: TrackingIdType[]
}

type TrackingIdType = {
    active: number,
    pixelId: string
}

type DataType = {
  apiKey: string,
  banKeys: string[],
  monitoringMode: MonitoringModeType,
  pxg: PxgType | undefined
}

const data: DataType = {
    "apiKey": "11111",
    "banKeys": ["ip", "userAgent"],
    "monitoringMode": {
        "isMonitoring": false,
        "dates": null
    },
    pxg: {
        "trackingIds": [
            {
                "active": 1,
                "pixelId": "12"
            },
            {
                "active": 1,
                "pixelId": "123"
            }
        ]
    }
};

const pixelIdToRemove = "12";

// Find the index of the object with the given pixelId
    const index: any = data.pxg?.trackingIds.findIndex((obj: TrackingIdType) => obj.pixelId === pixelIdToRemove);


if (index !== -1) {
  // Remove the object at the found index
  data.pxg?.trackingIds.splice(index, 1);

  // Remove the pxg object if the trackingIds array is empty
  if (data.pxg?.trackingIds.length === 0) {
    delete data.pxg;
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code with types but still I get an error

Comment: pixels.pxg.trackingIds.findIndex((obj: TrackingObject) => obj.pixelId === pixelId);
this is the issue

Comment: change that to:     data.pxg.trackingIds.findIndex((obj: TrackingObject) => obj.pixelId === pixelIdToRemove);

Comment: I have updated my answer to change the Type of DataType to allow the delete to work.